# c++ code to get ip address

Tags: c++, winapi

I know this question has been asked many times ,not sure where exactly is the problem.I have written a code to get the ip address of the local computer by referring **GetAdaptersAddresses**              function in the msdn library.The **printf** function in the else part is getting printed on the console screen.

The code is as follows.

```
  #include<WinSock2.h>
  #include<iphlpapi.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<Windows.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")


   int main(void )
   {
          PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;

          DWORD retval=0;
          ULONG outBufLen=sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES);


          retval=GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC,GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL,pAddresses, &outBufLen);

    if(retval==NO_ERROR)
     {
        while (pAddresses) {

          printf("\tAdapter name: %s\n", pAddresses->AdapterName);

          printf("Description: %wS\n", pAddresses->Description);
          printf("\tTransmit link speed: %I64u\n", pAddresses->TransmitLinkSpeed);
          printf("\tReceive link speed: %I64u\n", pAddresses->ReceiveLinkSpeed);

          pAddresses = pAddresses->Next;
      }
   }
  else
  {
   printf("\n There has been an error ");
  }

  free(pAddresses);
 }
```

Comment: Do you really want the local (LAN) ip-address or do you want the public (Internet) ip-address?

Comment: both ,now i'm not on an LAN .

Comment: The computer doesn't know by itself the public address if it is behind a router/NAT (as it's normally the case), you have to rely on some external service to tell it to you.

Comment: So if i hardcode the private ip adress in tcp ip properties ,it should display it rite ?.That's a good explanation @Matteo Italia

Comment: You can use http://whatismyipaddress.com/api to get your external IP programmatically, using an HTTP API.

Comment: @crowder : i'm able to get ipadress from ipconfig :) .

Comment: @SanthoshPai That's very likely not your external (public) IP, but rather the IP you've been assigned on your local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pAddresses` is not allocated. At least not in the code you are showing us. Have a look at the example at the bottom of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Specifically for the line `pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *) MALLOC(outBufLen);`.

Comment: Did it but didn't seem to work ,will try the same once i get back to college on monday.

Comment: Ok, please ask then. Also: The `retval` actually contains useful information, you might want to `printf("%i\n",retval)` and look up the error code it gives.

Comment: I'm getting the the retval as 111 .A nonzero return value means that the function is working fine rite.

Comment: retval 111 is ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So you need to allocate more!

Comment: Thanks @enzme followed the steps in the link and the thing seem to work . i'm having a trouble in making use of WSAAddressToString function to get the ip address of the computer . i will repost a new question for the same.